# Dynamic tag names with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using Jersey and JAXB to build a simple RESTful webservice
I have a HashMap of 'String' to 'Integer':

```
2010-04 -> 24 
2010-05 -> 45
```

I need to generate an XML response which looks like this:

```
 <map>
   <2010-04>24</2010-04>
   <2010-05>45</2010-05>
 </map>
```

What is the best way to generate dynamic tag names with JAXB?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this?  It's almost certainly a bad idea. Something like `<item month="2010-04">24</item>` is much nicer and easier to handle.

Comment: Agree, but unfortunately we have some existing code that is going to consume the file with that specific schema, and I am trying to avoid introducing any new changes there... but if this is not possible with JAXB, adding a name attribute would be the next best thing :)

Comment: You *might* be able to bend JAXB to your will, using various extensions/plugins/etc, but it's really not the tool for the job here.

Comment: Tag names cannot begin with digits in xml...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use an `@XmlAnyElement`-annotated property and return the elements as `JAXBElement`s:

```
private Map<String, Integer> months = ...;

@XmlAnyElement
public List<JAXBElement<Integer>> getMonths() {
    List<JAXBElement<Integer>> elements = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<Integer>>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> month: months.entrySet()) 
        elements.add(new JAXBElement(new QName(month.getKey()), 
                                     Integer.class, month.getValue()));
    return elements;
}
```

This approach is ugly, but not uglier than the XML it produces.

Comment: how do you unmarshal this?

Answer (score 22):

Also came into this kind of problem recently. After referencing axtavt's answer listed above (and a bunch of other question threads), I made a summary for this kind of problem:

1. A container class that holds a list (or array) of `JAXBElement`
   objects, where this list (or array) is annotated with
   `@XmlAnyElement`,  thus dynamic element names could be generated.
2. An `XmlAdapter` class that handles marshalling/unmarshalling between
   Map to/from this container class.
3. Annotate any Map fields of your java bean with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`,
   with this `XmlAdapter` class as its value (or you can simply use the
   container class directly, as you can see below).

Now I'll take `Map<String, String>` as an example here, where

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

will be marshalled into

```
<root>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
</root>
```

Below is the full code snippet & comments, as well as examples:

### 1, The Container (for @XmlAnyElement)

```
/**
 * <dl>
 * <dt>References:
 * </dt>
 * <dd>
 *  <ul>
 *      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382202/use-jaxb-xmlanyelement-type-of-style-to-return-dynamic-element-names">Dynamic element names in JAXB</a></li>
 *      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941479/jaxb-how-to-marshall-map-into-keyvalue-key">Marshal Map into key-value pairs</a></li>
 *      <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293493/dynamic-tag-names-with-jaxb">Dynamic tag names with JAXB</a></li>
 *  </ul>
 * </dd>
 * </dl>
 * @author MEC
 *
 */
@XmlType
public static class MapWrapper{
    private List<JAXBElement<String>> properties = new ArrayList<>();

    public MapWrapper(){

    }
    /**
     * <p>
     * Funny fact: due to type erasure, this method may return 
     * List<Element> instead of List<JAXBElement<String>> in the end;
     * </p>
     * <h4>WARNING: do not use this method in your programme</h4>
     * <p>
     * Thus to retrieve map entries you've stored in this MapWrapper, it's 
     * recommended to use {@link #toMap()} instead.
     * </p>
     * @return
     */
    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<JAXBElement<String>> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
    public void setProperties(List<JAXBElement<String>> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }




    /**
     * <p>
     * Only use {@link #addEntry(JAXBElement)} and {{@link #addEntry(String, String)}
     * when this <code>MapWrapper</code> instance is created by yourself 
     * (instead of through unmarshalling).
     * </p>
     * @param key map key
     * @param value map value
     */
    public void addEntry(String key, String value){
        JAXBElement<String> prop = new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(key), String.class, value);
        addEntry(prop);
    }
    public void addEntry(JAXBElement<String> prop){
        properties.add(prop);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MapWrapper [properties=" + toMap() + "]";
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * To Read-Only Map
     * </p>
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Map<String, String> toMap(){
        //Note: Due to type erasure, you cannot use properties.stream() directly when unmashalling is used..
        List<?> props = properties;
        return props.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MapWrapper::extractLocalName, MapWrapper::extractTextContent));
    }


    /**
     * <p>
     * Extract local name from <code>obj</code>, whether it's javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement or org.w3c.dom.Element;
     * </p>
     * @param obj
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static String extractLocalName(Object obj){

        Map<Class<?>, Function<? super Object, String>> strFuncs = new HashMap<>();
        strFuncs.put(JAXBElement.class, (jaxb) -> ((JAXBElement<String>)jaxb).getName().getLocalPart());
        strFuncs.put(Element.class, ele -> ((Element) ele).getLocalName());
        return extractPart(obj, strFuncs).orElse("");
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * Extract text content from <code>obj</code>, whether it's javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement or org.w3c.dom.Element;
     * </p>
     * @param obj
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static String extractTextContent(Object obj){
        Map<Class<?>, Function<? super Object, String>> strFuncs = new HashMap<>();
        strFuncs.put(JAXBElement.class, (jaxb) -> ((JAXBElement<String>)jaxb).getValue());
        strFuncs.put(Element.class, ele -> ((Element) ele).getTextContent());
        return extractPart(obj, strFuncs).orElse("");
    }

    /**
     * Check class type of <code>obj</code> according to types listed in <code>strFuncs</code> keys,
     * then extract some string part from it according to the extract function specified in <code>strFuncs</code>
     * values.
     * @param obj
     * @param strFuncs
     * @return
     */
    private static <ObjType, T> Optional<T> extractPart(ObjType obj, Map<Class<?>, Function<? super ObjType, T>> strFuncs){
        for(Class<?> clazz : strFuncs.keySet()){
            if(clazz.isInstance(obj)){
                return Optional.of(strFuncs.get(clazz).apply(obj));
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. For the JAXB Binding, all you need to pay attention is this
   `getProperties` method, which get annotated by `@XmlAnyElement`.
2. Two `addEntry` methods are introduced here for easy of use. They
   should be used carefully though, as things may turn out horribly
   wrong when they are used for a freshly unmarshalled `MapWrapper` through `JAXBContext` (instead of created by yourself through a `new` operator).
3. `toMap` is introduced here for info probe, i.e. help to check
   map entries stored in this `MapWrapper` instance.

### 2, The Adapter (XmlAdapter)

`XmlAdapter` is used in pair with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`, which in this case is only needed when `Map<String, String>` is used as a bean property.

```
/**
 * <p>
 * ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382202/use-jaxb-xmlanyelement-type-of-style-to-return-dynamic-element-names
 * </p>
 * @author MEC
 *
 */
public static class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapWrapper, Map<String, String>>{

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(MapWrapper v) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> map = v.toMap();

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public MapWrapper marshal(Map<String, String> m) throws Exception {
        MapWrapper wrapper = new MapWrapper();

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m.entrySet()){
             wrapper.addEntry(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(entry.getKey()), String.class, entry.getValue()));
        }

        return wrapper;
    }

}
```

### 3, Examples

Here are two examples showing usage of the container & adapter.

#### 3.1 Example 1

To map this xml:

```
<root>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
<root>
```

You can use the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class CustomMap extends MapWrapper{
    public CustomMap(){

    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
CustomMap map = new CustomMap();
map.addEntry("key1", "value1");
map.addEntry("key1", "value2");

StringWriter sb = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomMap.class).createMarshaller().marshal(map, sb);
out.println(sb.toString());
```

Note that no `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` is used here.

#### 3.2 Example 2

To map this xml:

```
<root>
    <map>
        <key1>value1</key1>
        <key2>value2</key2>
    </map>
    <other>other content</other>
</root>
```

You can use the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlType(propOrder={"map", "other"})
public class YetAnotherBean{
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    private String other;
    public YetAnotherBean(){

    }
    public void putEntry(String key, String value){
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    @XmlElement(name="map")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
    public Map<String, String> getMap(){
        return map;
    }
    public void setMap(Map<String, String> map){
        this.map = map;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="other")
    public String getOther(){
        return other;
    }
    public void setOther(String other){
        this.other = other;
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
YetAnotherBean yab = new YetAnotherBean();
yab.putEntry("key1", "value1");
yab.putEntry("key2", "value2");
yab.setOther("other content");

StringWriter sb = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext.newInstance(YetAnotherBean.class).createMarshaller().marshal(yab, sb);
out.println(sb.toString());
```

Note that `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` is applied onto the `Map<String, String>` field with `MapAdapter` as its value.

#### 3.3 Example 3

Now let's add add some attributes to these elements. Due to some mysterious reasons, I have this kind of XML structure to map:

```
<sys-config>
  <sys-params>
    <ACCESSLOG_FILE_BY attr="C" desc="AccessLog file desc">SYSTEM</ACCESSLOG_FILE_BY>
    <ACCESSLOG_WRITE_MODE attr="D" desc="">DB</ACCESSLOG_WRITE_MODE>
    <CHANEG_BUTTON_IMAGES attr="E" desc="Button Image URL, eh, boolean value. ...Wait, what?">FALSE</CHANEG_BUTTON_IMAGES>
  </sys-params>
</sys-config>
```

As you can see, system parameter names are all set to be the element's name instead of as its attribute. To resolve this problem we can use a little help from `JAXBElement` again:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="sys-config")
public class SysParamConfigXDO{
    private SysParamEntries sysParams = new SysParamEntries();

    public SysParamConfigXDO(){

    }

    public void addSysParam(String name, String value, String attr, String desc){
        sysParams.addEntry(name, value, attr, desc);;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="sys-params")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SysParamEntriesAdapter.class)
    public SysParamEntries getSysParams() {
        return sysParams;
    }

    public void setSysParams(SysParamEntries sysParams) {
        this.sysParams = sysParams;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SysParamConfigXDO [sysParams=" + sysParams + "]";
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class SysParamXDO extends SysParamEntriesWrapper{
    public SysParamXDO(){

    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@XmlType
public class SysParamEntriesWrapper{
    /**
     * <p>
     * Here is the tricky part:
     * <ul>
     *  <li>When this <code>SysParamEntriesWrapper</code> is created by yourself, objects 
     * stored in this <code>entries</code> list is of type SystemParamEntry</li>
     *  <li>Yet during the unmarshalling process, this <code>SysParamEntriesWrapper</code> is 
     * created by the JAXBContext, thus objects stored in the <code>entries</code> is 
     * of type Element actually.</li>
     * </ul>
     * </p>
     */
    List<JAXBElement<SysParamEntry>> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    public SysParamEntriesWrapper(){
    }


    public void addEntry(String name, String value, String attr, String desc){
        addEntry(new SysParamEntry(name, value, attr, desc));
    }
    public void addEntry(String name, String value){
        addEntry(new SysParamEntry(name, value));
    }

    public void addEntry(SysParamEntry entry){
        JAXBElement<SysParamEntry> bean = new JAXBElement<SysParamEntry>(new QName("", entry.getName()), SysParamEntry.class, entry);
        entries.add(bean);
    }

    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<JAXBElement<SysParamEntry>> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
    public void setEntries(List<JAXBElement<SysParamEntry>> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SysParammEntriesWrapper [entries=" + toMap() + "]";
    }


    public Map<String, SysParamEntry> toMap(){
        Map<String, SysParamEntry> retval = new HashMap<>();

        List<?> entries = this.entries;

        entries.stream().map(SysParamEntriesWrapper::convertToParamEntry).
            forEach(entry -> retval.put(entry.getName(), entry));;
        return retval;
    }


    private static SysParamEntry convertToParamEntry(Object entry){
        String name = extractName(entry);
        String attr = extractAttr(entry);
        String desc = extractDesc(entry);
        String value = extractValue(entry);
        return new SysParamEntry(name, value, attr, desc);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static String extractName(Object entry){
        return extractPart(entry, nameExtractors).orElse("");
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static String extractAttr(Object entry){
        return extractPart(entry, attrExtractors).orElse("");
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static String extractDesc(Object entry){
        return extractPart(entry, descExtractors).orElse("");
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static String extractValue(Object entry){
        return extractPart(entry, valueExtractors).orElse("");
    }
    private static <ObjType, RetType> Optional<RetType> extractPart(ObjType obj, Map<Class<?>,
            Function<? super ObjType, RetType>> extractFuncs ){
        for(Class<?> clazz : extractFuncs.keySet()){
            if(clazz.isInstance(obj)){
                return Optional.ofNullable(extractFuncs.get(clazz).apply(obj));
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }


    private static Map<Class<?>, Function<? super Object, String>> nameExtractors = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<Class<?>, Function<? super Object, String>> attrExtractors = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<Class<?>, Function<? super Object, String>> descExtractors = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<Class<?>, Function<? super Object, String>> valueExtractors = new HashMap<>();
    static{
        nameExtractors.put(JAXBElement.class, jaxb -> ((JAXBElement<SysParamEntry>)jaxb).getName().getLocalPart());
        nameExtractors.put(Element.class, ele -> ((Element) ele).getLocalName());

        attrExtractors.put(JAXBElement.class, jaxb -> ((JAXBElement<SysParamEntry>)jaxb).getValue().getAttr());
        attrExtractors.put(Element.class, ele -> ((Element) ele).getAttribute("attr"));

        descExtractors.put(JAXBElement.class, jaxb -> ((JAXBElement<SysParamEntry>)jaxb).getValue().getDesc());
        descExtractors.put(Element.class, ele -> ((Element) ele).getAttribute("desc"));

        valueExtractors.put(JAXBElement.class, jaxb -> ((JAXBElement<SysParamEntry>)jaxb).getValue().getValue());
        valueExtractors.put(Element.class, ele -> ((Element) ele).getTextContent());
    }
}

public class SysParamEntriesAdapter extends XmlAdapter<SysParamEntriesWrapper, SysParamEntries>{

    @Override
    public SysParamEntries unmarshal(SysParamEntriesWrapper v) throws Exception {
        SysParamEntries retval = new SysParamEntries();
        v.toMap().values().stream().forEach(retval::addEntry);
        return retval;
    }

    @Override
    public SysParamEntriesWrapper marshal(SysParamEntries v) throws Exception {
        SysParamEntriesWrapper entriesWrapper = new SysParamEntriesWrapper();
        v.getEntries().forEach(entriesWrapper::addEntry);
        return entriesWrapper;
    }
}

public class SysParamEntries{
    List<SysParamEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();;
    public SysParamEntries(){

    }
    public SysParamEntries(List<SysParamEntry> entries) {
        super();
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    public void addEntry(SysParamEntry entry){
        entries.add(entry);
    }
    public void addEntry(String name, String value){
        addEntry(name, value, "C");
    }

    public void addEntry(String name, String value, String attr){
        addEntry(name, value, attr, "");
    }

    public void addEntry(String name, String value, String attr, String desc){
        entries.add(new SysParamEntry(name, value, attr, desc));
    }
    public List<SysParamEntry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
    public void setEntries(List<SysParamEntry> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SystemParamEntries [entries=" + entries + "]";
    }

}
@XmlType
public class SysParamEntry{
    String name;
    String value = "";
    String attr = "";
    String desc = "";
    public SysParamEntry(){

    }

    public SysParamEntry(String name, String value) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public SysParamEntry(String name, String value, String attr) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.attr = attr;
    }

    public SysParamEntry(String name, String value, String attr, String desc) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.attr = attr;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    @XmlTransient
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @XmlValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name="attr")
    public String getAttr() {
        return attr;
    }
    public void setAttr(String attr) {
        this.attr = attr;
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name="desc")
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SystemParamEntry [name=" + name + ", value=" + value + ", attr=" + attr + ", desc=" + desc + "]";
    }
}
```

And it's time for test:

```
//Marshal
SysParamConfigXDO xdo = new SysParamConfigXDO();
xdo.addSysParam("ACCESSLOG_FILE_BY", "SYSTEM", "C", "AccessLog file desc");
xdo.addSysParam("ACCESSLOG_WRITE_MODE", "DB", "D", "");
xdo.addSysParam("CHANEG_BUTTON_IMAGES", "FALSE", "E", "Button Image URL, eh, boolean value. ...Wait, what?");

JAXBContext jaxbCtx = JAXBContext.newInstance(SysParamConfigXDO.class, SysParamEntries.class);
jaxbCtx.createMarshaller().marshal(xdo, System.out);


//Unmarshal
Path xmlFile = Paths.get("path_to_the_saved_xml_file.xml");

JAXBContext jaxbCtx = JAXBContext.newInstance(SysParamConfigXDO.class, SysParamEntries.class);
SysParamConfigXDO xdo = (SysParamConfigXDO) jaxbCtx.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xmlFile.toFile());
out.println(xdo.toString());
```

Comment: In Example 2 I want this type of XML generation :<root>
    
        <key1>value1</key1>
        <key2>value2</key2>
    
    <other>other content</other>
</root> . Just don't want extra <map></map> tag. Can I achive this ?

Comment: Pretty useful piece of information. Already upvoted! One more question: what if my XML structure has dynamic sub fields, as follows:

<sys-config>
  <sys-params>
    <ACCESSLOG_FILE_BY attr="C" desc="AccessLog file desc">SYSTEM</ACCESSLOG_FILE_BY>
    <ACCESSLOG_WRITE_MODE attr="D" desc="">DB</ACCESSLOG_WRITE_MODE>
    <CHANEG_BUTTON_IMAGES attr="E" desc="Button Image URL, eh, boolean value. ...Wait, what?">FALSE</CHANEG_BUTTON_IMAGES>
 <author>
  <personnel_info attr="Name Surname" desc="This is a person">Export</personnel_info>
 </author>
  </sys-params>
</sys-config>

Answer (score 5):

Maybe somebody is interested in an easier solution with marshall and unmarshall example.
It is not a map but still a key-value solution because we are using `JAXBElement` with a key (=localname) and value (=textcontent).

```
@XmlRootElement(name="map")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlMap {
    //one caveat (as mec_test_1 pointed out) unmarshalled objects are from type org.w3c.dom.Element and during marshall it is JAXBElement
    @XmlAnyElement
    List<JAXBElement<String>> dates = new ArrayList<>();
```

To unmarshall lets say this xml file

```
<map>
   <2019-01-01>Yes</2019-01-01>
   <2019-02-01>No</2019-02-01>
</map>
```

You have to run:

```
JAXBContext c = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlMap.class);
XmlMap map = c.createUnmarshaller().unmarshall(new File("xmlfile.xml"));
//access the objects via
System.out.println("Key: " + ((org.w3c.dom.Element) map.dates.get(0)).getLocalName());
System.out.println("Value: " + ((org.w3c.dom.Element) map.dates.get(0)).getTextContent());
```

An to marshall a object:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

XmlMap xmlMap = new XmlMap();
xmlMap.dates.add(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("key"), String.class, "value"));
xmlMap.dates.add(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("2019-01-01"), String.class, "Yes"));

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlMap.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.marshal(verzObj, System.out);
```

Output:

```
<map>
   <key>val</key>
   <2019-01-01>Yes</2019-01-01>
</map>
```