# JAXB unmarshalling XML element with different tags

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have xml file with this kind of structure:

```
<root>
    <elements>
        <element>
            <id>1</id>
            <tag1>some string</tag1>
        </element>
        <element>
            <id>1</id>
            <tag2>some other string</tag2>
        </element>
    </elements>
</root>
```

Is it possible to unmarshall that kind of XML to an object. Problem is that each element has some tags that are unique. I was thinking to put those values in List, but i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Use Map<String, String>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and quite easy, make an Element object for the element tag and put there all possible sub tags, if JAX-B can't find them in you XML it will leave them as null, so you will get a decent object.

A simple JAX-B intro can be found here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

If the possible sub tags of the element tag are just too many, change rapidly or are unknown you could try to go with a <String, String> structure, something like the one described here: [How to serialize HashTable<String, String> to XML using JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534500/how-to-serialize-hashtablestring-string-to-xml-using-jaxb)

But for most cases I would chose the first option.