# XML serialization of nested objects in JAVA

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-serialization

I am using JAXB to serialize and deserialize java objects.
Classes are as:

```
    public class Level1Class
    {
        String Id;

        HashMap<String,Level2Class> level2Map = new HashMap<String,Level2Class>();


    }

    public class Level2Class
    {
        String Id;
    }
```

I want to serialize and deserialize object of Level1Class. 
Please suggest annotation for classes and fields. 

What else do I need to include
1. default constructor
2. getter setter of fields

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534500/how-to-serialize-hashtablestring-string-to-xml-using-jaxb  This may help.

Answer (score 0):

To make an object serializable, you just have to let it implement `Serializable` and make sure that every field of this object is serializable as well.