# JAXB: how to marshall HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>?

Tags: java, xml, hashmap, jaxb, marshalling

I have a complex structure of data, that can describe by HashMap inside HashMap. I need create XML file of structure. Like this:

```
<map>
    <key1>
        <map>
           <key1>someString1</key1>
           <key2>someString2</key2>
        </map>
    </key1>
    <key2>
        <map>
           <key1>someString1</key1>
           <key2>someString2</key2>
        </map>
    </key2>
</map>
```

But I noticed, JAXB has some problems with it. Is there any way to make XML from maps?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use JAXB to serialize directly a `Map` in to `XML`. You will have to use a `Wrapper Class`, that will serve you as the object tree.
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534500/how-to-serialize-hashtablestring-string-to-xml-using-jaxb) will help you.