# Hashmap not supported

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, hashmap

I'm trying to generate webservice that type Hashmap but I'm getting the following error :

```
hashmap that is not supported by the jax-rpc
```

my code :

```
public String insertTest(HashMap<Integer, Integer> checkBoxState){

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> mapEntry : checkBoxState
        .entrySet()) {
    int SID = mapEntry.getKey();
    int status = mapEntry.getValue();
    System.out.println("student it " + SID + "status"+status);
}

return null;    
}
```

I'm using tomcat 7

So I want a simple way to get it work

Comment: Recommended to use JAXWS as JAXRPC is outdated

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107875/jax-ws-how-to-make-a-soap-response-return-a-hashmap-object

Comment: how to change from JAXRPC to JAXWS  cuz I'm searched and I'm confused

Comment: what ide are you using? with some ide is easy to set jax-ws

Comment: eclipse juno and javaee6 i'm sure wtf is installed