# getting HashMap objects in SoapUI

Tags: java, soap, hashmap, soapui

as part of the requirement I have to return HashMap objects from a function. I'm using SoapUI to test the webservice I produce. Through SoapUI I'm sending the request to the function but nothing is displayed in the SoapUI response pane. Is there any way to display HashMap objects in SoapUI service response window?

Comment: What type of WS are you using
Rest vs SOAP (JAX-WS, JAX-RPC) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107875/jax-ws-how-to-make-a-soap-response-return-a-hashmap-object

Comment: @user1933888: we are using SOAP

Comment: SoapUI will display XML. If your service is SOAP, you can see what your response is suppose to look like in the WSDL.