# JDeveloper [JAVA] - Define response message in Webmethod

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper to build webservices and testing them with the utility "HTTP Analyzer".
However I can't seem to create an output that works when I call that webmethod from HTTP Analyzer.

Example code:

```
@WebMethod
public HashMap <Integer, Integer> DeleteSomething (Object something) {
  return class.deleteSth(something); //This returns HashMap
}
```

The only thing displayed in the return message is the code '200 OK'.

How do I return something from the webmethod into HTTP Analyzer?

EDIT: I've managed to return something by using the HashMap values to create a List of Strings and returning the List instead. However I would still like to know why the HashMap didn't work.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List can be converted internally by SOAP WS. Map is something which explicitly needs adapter to convert into appropriate Response.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107875/jax-ws-how-to-make-a-soap-response-return-a-hashmap-object) explains the example of converting and wrapping up the response.

Briefly, using `MapAdapter` class helps JAXB in wrapping the response. SOAP can handle List being a member to a POJO class and not being the direct member in the older versions. A [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-28) logged for this.