# JAXB mapping for a map

Tags: java, jaxb

Using JAXB, how to map `<entry key="childResources">` below?

I tried mapping it to a Map, to a list of @XmlRootElement anotated classes and other ways, without success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<map>    
  <entry key="extraProperties">        
    <map>            
      <entry key="methods">                
        <list>                    
          <map>                        
            <entry key="name" value="GET" />
          </map>                    
          <map />                    
          <map>                        
            <entry key="name" value="POST" />                        
            <entry key="messageParameters">                            
              <map>                                
                <entry key="id">                                    
                  <map>                                        
                    <entry key="acceptableValues" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="optional" value="false" />                                        
                    <entry key="defaultValue" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="type" value="string" />
                  </map>                                
                </entry>                                
                <entry key="enabled">                                    
                  <map>                                        
                    <entry key="acceptableValues" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="optional" value="true" />                                        
                    <entry key="defaultValue" value="true" />                                        
                    <entry key="type" value="boolean" />
                  </map>                                
                </entry>                                
                <entry key="factoryclass">                                    
                  <map>                                        
                    <entry key="acceptableValues" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="optional" value="false" />                                        
                    <entry key="defaultValue" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="type" value="string" />
                  </map>                                
                </entry>                                
                <entry key="description">                                    
                  <map>                                        
                    <entry key="acceptableValues" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="optional" value="true" />                                        
                    <entry key="defaultValue" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="type" value="string" />
                  </map>                                
                </entry>                                
                <entry key="target">                                    
                  <map>                                        
                    <entry key="acceptableValues" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="optional" value="true" />                                        
                    <entry key="defaultValue" value="server" />                                        
                    <entry key="type" value="string" />
                  </map>                                
                </entry>                                
                <entry key="property">                                    
                  <map>                                        
                    <entry key="acceptableValues" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="optional" value="true" />                                        
                    <entry key="defaultValue" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="type" value="string" />
                  </map>                                
                </entry>                                
                <entry key="restype">                                    
                  <map>                                        
                    <entry key="acceptableValues" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="optional" value="false" />                                        
                    <entry key="defaultValue" value="" />                                        
                    <entry key="type" value="string" />
                  </map>                                
                </entry>                            
              </map>                        
            </entry>                    
          </map>                
        </list>            
      </entry>            
      <entry key="commands">                
        <list />
      </entry>            
      <entry key="childResources">                
        <map>                    
          <entry key="ab/cd" value="http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/custom-resource/ab%2Fcd" />                    
          <entry key="xx" value="http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/xx" />
        </map>            
      </entry>        
    </map>    
  </entry>    
  <entry key="message" value="" />    
  <entry key="exit_code" value="SUCCESS" />    
  <entry key="command" value="custom-resource" />
</map>
```

Comment: an `<entry>` can have `a single <map>` or `a single <list>`?

Comment: I guess a <entry key="childResources"> has a single map with multiple entries each of which has a key/value pair

Comment: I guess <entry key="childResources"> should be mapped to a Map<String, String> or a Map<String, URI>.

Comment: What was the error when you mapped to a Map?

Comment: Why don't you use XPATH expression to get values you need? With JAXB you can map document structure but you can't make your mapping depend on content of an attribute like `key="childResources"`.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov I'm quite sure it can. This is generated by Glassfish, which probably gets it done with Jersey with some mapping annotations. I'd like to map it back, it works from almost anything except this property.

Comment: @FlavioCysne no error, but null values, empty lists, ...

Comment: I think there's a possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941479/jaxb-how-to-marshall-map-into-keyvalue-key)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The java.util.Map interface has no provider to marshal/unmarshal its instances. You'll have to write a class that extends `XmlAdapter` and annotate the `java.util.Map` attribute with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyMapAdapter.class)`.

After a while on Google looking for `jax-rs java.util.map`, I ended up with the codes bellow. In my case I have named my adapter as *XmlStringMapAdapter* instead of *MyMapAdapter*.

*ServiceDefinition.java*

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entry")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ServiceDefinition {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String key;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlStringMapAdapter.class)
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // getters & setters
}
```

*EntryElement.java*

```
public class EntryElement {

    @XmlAttribute public String key;
    @XmlAttribute public String value;

    public EntryElement() {}

    public EntryElement(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

*MapElement.java*

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "map")
public class MapElement {

    @XmlElement(name = "entry")
    public List<EntryElement> entries = new ArrayList<EntryElement>();

    public void addEntry(String key, String value) {
        entries.add(new EntryElement(key, value));
    }

}
```

*XmlStringMapAdapter.java*

```
public class XmlStringMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapElement, Map<String, String>> {

    @Override
    public MapElement marshal(Map<String, String> v) throws Exception {

        if (v == null || v.isEmpty()) {return null;}

        MapElement map = new MapElement();

        for (String key : v.keySet()) {
            map.addEntry(key, v.get(key));
        }

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(MapElement v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {return null;}

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(v.entries.size());

        for(EntryElement entry: v.entries) {
            map.put(entry.key, entry.value);
        }

        return map;
    }

}
```

And bellow is a class that I used to test the new map adapter.

*ServiceResouce.java*

```
@Path("service")
public class ServiceResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @GET
    @Path("definition")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response getDefinition() {
        ServiceDefinition def = new ServiceDefinition();
        UriBuilder b = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder();

        def.setKey("childResources");
        def.getMap().put("ab/cd", b.path("ab/cd").build(this).getPath());
        def.getMap().put("xx", b.path("xx").build(this).getPath());

        return Response.ok(def).build();
    }
}
```

Output from the resource above is as shown bellow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry key="childResources">
    <map>
        <entry key="ab/cd" value="http://localhost:8080/management/resources/ab/cd" />
        <entry key="xx" value="http://localhost:8080/management/resources/xx" />
    </map>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the XSD for your document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="map" type="mapType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="entryType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="mapType" name="map" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="listType" name="list" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="key" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="listType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="mapType" name="map" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="mapType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="entryType" name="entry" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Compare it to mapping you did for your classes. Would be nice to see you classes and annotations it question formulation.

You can generate model with mappings from this schema with many different utilities for IDEs like Eclipse and Intellij or via CLI.