# How can I use HashMaps in Web service using Apche axis?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, hashmap, apache-axis

I'm doing an assignment where I have to use a web service using apache axis (Using eclips Mars) to make a desktop application in Java. It has to use an existing dynamic web project I already created.
Web project was to add/remove companies and employee details in a (Oracle) database in a web interface. It worked as required. But when the web service was created, It doesn't allow me to create a web client. It gives this error:

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:
java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault "IOException"
in operation "IOException", in binding getCompanies
```

Apparently, it wont allow me to return `HashMap`s from methods I created. (When I changed my whole project without returning Hashmaps, I can create the client) But I need to get HashMaps. 
Are there any way to get `HashMap`s from the web service I created ???

I've refereed [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250222/how-to-use-hashmap-as-a-parameter-in-web-service) in SO. But I have no idea what's the accepted answer was saying.

**EDIT:**

OK. Now I know that I can't use HashMaps in web services as they can't be marshal and unmarshal. Then I found [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329388/jaxb-mapping-for-a-map) which I tried. But the problem still stands. (I guess I didn't used the answer mentioned above correctly.) As a beginner in this field, I actually don't get how to wrap (Or serialize) Hashmap and retrieve it back. Can someone show an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to wrap your HashMap in a class and create a custom adapter using it with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` to allow JAXB to make the object serialisation correctly.

```
public class Response {
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)    

  HashMap<Integer, Student> students;

  public HashMap<Integer, Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
  }

  public void setStudents(HashMap<Integer, Student> map) {
    this.students = map;
  }
}
```

Then just use this class as a return value of your web method.

**See more:**

[Doc API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html)
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329388/jaxb-mapping-for-a-map)

Comment: When I use this, It gives me this error:
`Class<MapAdapter> cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: You have to create that class. It will contains how the hash map will be serialized.

Comment: Just search for `jaxb custom adapter` in order to understand what you have to do

Comment: I still not understood this correctly I guess. 
I got [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329388/jaxb-mapping-for-a-map) And I implemented those classes. But still it gives me the same error.