# Jersey 2.0 HashMap conversion to/from Json

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I've Json like this, that is provided by a webservice:

```
{   ... 
    "metadata": {
        "name": "test_server",
        "server_type": "test",
         ...
    },
     ...
}
```

I'm using GLasshfish, Netbeans and Jersey framework to consume web resources from the WS.
According to Jersey features, I use some Java classes that map the Json structure, in order to obtain the conversion in data structures using Jersey (and JAX-RS annotation). For the mentioned Json packet I've created this class:

```
public class Server 
    {
      ...

      private Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<String, String>();
      ...
      public Server(){}
    }
```

The mapping works all fine, except for the "metadata" attribute, that is structured like a random-lenght map, with a String as both key and value.
After that conversion, the result is that:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "entry":[]
    }
}
```

I've some similar case, but no solution. It seems that Jersey 2.0 isn't able to convert a map stile Json attribute in the corresponding Java data structure Object (HashMap).
There aren't no exception or errors on the server, but the printed json map is always containing "entry":[], and I don't know where it comes out from.
With other object types or data types I've no problem (List, int, String... all works fine).
Can anyone help me? Thanks for support!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926505/jersey-jax-rs-return-a-map-as-xml-json

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the JSON string that is provided by you and it works using `TypeReference` and `ObjectMapper` that return `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` as per this JSON string.

Here is the code:

```
String jsonString = "{\"metadata\": {\"name\": \"test_server\",\"server_type\": \"test\"}}";

TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> typeRef = 
                        new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> jsonObject = 
                                       mapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("metadata"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Three might be some issue wiht the JSON string");
}
```

output:

```
{name=test_server, server_type=test}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but using the solution provided by you, I will not use the class auto mapping from/to Json in Jersey Moxy style! (In fact your solution is a low based Json processing, based on Jackson library, according to https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json)