# JAXB XML Dynamic Unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

So I have a couple of XMLs which I'm trying to unmarshal.

One XML can look like this:

```
<TABLE>
    <RECORDS>
        <RECORD>
            <DOC_ID>some value</DOC_ID>
            <ENTITY_ID>some value</ENTITY_ID>
            ...more entries
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD>
            <DOC_ID>some value</DOC_ID>
            <ENTITY_ID>some value</ENTITY_ID>
            ...more entries
        </RECORD>
    </RECORDS>
</TABLE>
```

Another XML can also look like this:

```
<TABLE>
    <RECORDS>
        <RECORD>
            <SUB_ID>some value</SUB_ID>
            <CASE_DOC_ID>some value</CASE_DOC_ID>
            ...more entries
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD>
            <SUB_ID>some value</SUB_ID>
            <CASE_DOC_ID>some value</CASE_DOC_ID>
            ...more entries
        </RECORD>
    </RECORDS>
</TABLE>
```

Each XML always has TABLE as root and RECORDS as a child and RECORD as grandchild just that the data in RECORD is different.

I don't want to marshal anything, just unmarshal and get the data.

Inside my Table Class I have

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "TABLE")
public class Table {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
    private Map<String, String> RECORDS;

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return RECORDS;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, String> record) {
        this.RECORDS = record;
    }
```

}

I took MapAdapter from this link:
[JAXB Marshal and Unmarshal Map to/from <key>value</key>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837194/jaxb-marshal-and-unmarshal-map-to-from-keyvalue-key)

**My issue is this: 
I would like to be able to get each Tag name in the record (DOC_ID/SUB_ID or whatever in the XML) and each of it's values as Strings when I pass in the XML but I'm not sure how to go about it.**

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

2 new questions!
I realized I would probably need a list of Maps for all the records.

- I managed to get the last record's keys and values using the Table class above. How do I turn it into a list of Maps so I can get each record instead of just the last?
- Another question is the Table class only works if I don't have a RECORDS tag in my xml. How do I fix that?

Comment: Any help with what? You didn't ask any question, and you didn't say what issue you have. Please edit the question and clarify it.

Comment: Bolded my issue and brought it to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to annotate the `Map` with the `MapAdapter` from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32837194/5221149) you provided, so you need to create a subclass.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
public class Record extends HashMap<String, String> {
}
```

Then your Table class is simple enough, though you need to annotate with [`@XmlElementWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html) to get the extra level of XML.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TABLE")
public class Table {
    private List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "RECORDS")
    @XmlElement(name = "RECORD")
    public List<Record> getRecords() {
        return this.records;
    }
    public void setRecords(List<Record> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }
}
```

When working with JAXB and the parsing doesn't load all the information, I've found that it helps to first write code to *generate* XML, because you can then see, in the generated XML, how the JAXB mappings differ from what you expected/intended.

It's easier to create sample data if you add a few helper methods to the above classes, so lets do that first:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
public class Record extends HashMap<String, String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Record addElement(String name, String value) {
        put(name, value);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Record" + super.toString();
    }
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TABLE")
public class Table {
    private List<Record> records;

    public Table() {
        this.records = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public Table(Record... records) {
        this.records = Arrays.asList(records);
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "RECORDS")
    @XmlElement(name = "RECORD")
    public List<Record> getRecords() {
        return this.records;
    }
    public void setRecords(List<Record> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Table" + this.records.toString();
    }
}
```

Then we can easily write test code to see that it all works ok.

*Build data to generate as XML*

```
Table table1 = new Table(
        new Record().addElement("DOC_ID", "some value")
                    .addElement("ENTITY_ID", "some value"),
        new Record().addElement("SUB_ID", "some value")
                    .addElement("CASE_DOC_ID", "some value")
);
System.out.println(table1);
```

```
Table[Record{DOC_ID=some value, ENTITY_ID=some value}, Record{SUB_ID=some value, CASE_DOC_ID=some value}]
```

*Generate XML*

```
String xml;
try (StringWriter out = new StringWriter()) {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Table.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(table1, out);
    xml = out.toString();
}
System.out.println(xml);
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TABLE>
    <RECORDS>
        <RECORD>
            <DOC_ID>some value</DOC_ID>
            <ENTITY_ID>some value</ENTITY_ID>
        </RECORD>
        <RECORD>
            <SUB_ID>some value</SUB_ID>
            <CASE_DOC_ID>some value</CASE_DOC_ID>
        </RECORD>
    </RECORDS>
</TABLE>
```

We can confirm that the JAXB mappings generate the XML format we intend to parse.

*Parse XML*

```
Table table2;
{
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Table.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    table2 = (Table) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
}
System.out.println(table2);
```

```
Table[{DOC_ID=some value, ENTITY_ID=some value}, {SUB_ID=some value, CASE_DOC_ID=some value}]
```

As you can see, the parsed data has all the values, and it matches the original data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. However just to note that DOC_ID and SUB_ID are in different XML files and that each record has around 20-30 tags so I didn't want to type them out manually.

Comment: @MosesKoh This is just an examples that shows that a `<RECORD>` element can contain dynamically named sub-elements. Whether a single XML file can have disparate fields in multiple `<RECORD>` elements is besides the point.

Comment: @MosesKoh If you have `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` (I don't), put the `@XmlElement` on the field. If you don't specify access type, put `@XmlElement` on the getter method (like I did), because access type defaults to `PUBLIC_MEMBER` (and the field is `private`, right?)

Comment: whoops I forgot I added `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`. It's running now thanks. Now i need to figure out why my values come out as null when reading the file (I'm passing in a File type by the way). The keys are there but not the values.