# Java: remove < and > from text in XML (not tags)

Tags: java, xml, jtidy

I'm having a hard time escaping xml to be processed by Java. I'm using JTidy to escape unwanted characters, but struggle to remove "<" and ">" from values such as `<tag> capacity < 1000 </tag>`

I'm using below code to escape the input

```
    public String CleanXML(String input){

        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-16");
        tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-16");
        tidy.setWraplen(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        tidy.setXmlOut(true);
        tidy.setSmartIndent(true);
        tidy.setXmlTags(true);
        tidy.setMakeClean(true);
        tidy.setForceOutput(true);
        tidy.setQuiet(true);
        tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
        StringReader in = new StringReader(input);
        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
        tidy.parse(in, out);

        return out.toString();
    }
```

Comment: What is the expected value from `<tag> capacity < 1000 </tag>`?

Comment: Id use something like: <tag> capacity esc(<) 1000 </tag>

Comment: What kind of input are you starting with? A string that contains both tags (like `<a>`) and unescaped angle brackets (like `size < 7`)?. That's pretty dirty input, look at how it was created and try to create something cleaner rather than tidying up the mess afterwards.

Comment: Id like to.. , but problem is that the data comes from technicians tablets all over the world, this option is kind of unreal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following function

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<tag>(.+?)</tag>", Pattern.DOTALL);

public String CleanXML(String input){
    final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String value = matcher.group(1);
        String valueReplace = value.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
        input.replace(value,valueReplace);
    }
    return input;        
}
```

It uses regular expression search to get values between tags then, remove all non alphanumeric characters. Regular expressions and basic idea was gained from [Java regex to extract text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560672/java-regex-to-extract-text-between-tags)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove tag terminals of XML, just convert it to a map and build string as you required refer [XML to map in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598250/how-to-convert-string-xml-to-mapstring-string).

If you want to clean attribute values, you can iterate map and clean it then build a string or re convert it to the XML by [map to XML in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893912/using-jaxb-to-create-xml-from-map)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but we are using service bus that accepts XML string in plain UTF-8. I need to escape that string before parsing it into XML object, thus I do not have neither map nor xml to work with unless I parse the string (which in case it contains "<" within the value fails). Any Idea in this case?

Comment: didn't you try an ASCII value range check on string?

Comment: I have not .. how would you implement it?

Comment: try the function in following answer.