# Jersey 2.x post call MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using Jersey version 2.29 /java 1.8 on tomcat version 8.5 and trying to retrurn the `hasmap<String,String>` from jersey rest post service call.

I am getting below exception on server when it is trying to write the hasmap in response.

**Aug 23, 2019 10:20:47 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.LinkedHashMap, genericType=java.util.Map.**

Below are the details of pom.xml,server and jersey client side code.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
</dependency>
 <dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId> 
    <version>2.3.1</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId> 
    <version>2.3.1</version> </dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Client Code**

```
ClientConfig configuration=new ClientConfig();
Client restClientConfig = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration);
WebTarget webTarget=restClientConfig.target("http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/testMap");
HashMap<String,String> mapStr=new HashMap<String,String>();     
mapStr.put("a","1");
mapStr.put("b","2");
webTarget.request()
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
.post(Entity.json(mapStr));

Map<String,String> responseMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
GenericType<Map<String,String>> entity = new GenericType<Map<String,String>>() {};
Response xmlResponse = Response.ok(entity).build();
System.out.println("XMLResponse Is :" + xmlResponse + ":"+ responseMap.size());
```

**Jersey Post Service  code**

```
@POST
@Path("/testMap")
@Produces(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Map<String,String>  postMapMessage(Map<String,String> mapMessage) {
    System.out.println("It is been invoked....and this time we will add the new MapMessage");
    if(mapMessage!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("Size of the Map Message:" + mapMessage.size());
        mapMessage.put("c","3");
    }
    return mapMessage;
}
```

I have tried several solutions found on internet but nothing seems to be working for this.

Can anybody please tell me what wrong I am doing in above code snippet?

Comment: `Maps` don't map well to XML. Unlike JSON, XML needs a root element and is more suitable for a tree structure. Maps are more suitable for key/value pair data, which XML is not. Hence, Maps are not supported (out of the box) in JAXB binding library. It's not impossible to work with Maps, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3941479/2587435), but there are just no "natural" solutions.

Comment: @Paul I have able to partially fixed the issue by creating the wrapper class. But when I am trying to create the map of Map<String,BookBo> it seems to be failing. Do you know any reason why it is failing?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to partially fix the issue by creating the below wrapper class.

```
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
    public class JaxrsMapWrapper<T,K> {

        private Map<T,K> map;

        public JaxrsMapWrapper(){

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return  map .toString();
        }

        public void setMap(Map<T,K> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        public Map<T,K> getMap() {
            return map;
        }
    }
```

By using the above class below getservice returning the typeof Map is working absolutly fine.

```
@GET
@Path("/mapWarpperReceive")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public JaxrsMapWrapper<String,String> getWarpperMapMsgStr()
{

System.out.println("Returning the MapMessage as String ");
Map<String,String> originalMap=new  HashMap<String,String>(){{put("a","a");put("b","b");}};
JaxrsMapWrapper<String,String> jaxRsMapWrapper=new JaxrsMapWrapper<>();
jaxRsMapWrapper.setMap(originalMap);
return jaxRsMapWrapper;

}
```

But when I am trying to use the same class JaxrsMapWrapper with type of Map it is throwing Error 500 Internal server error while invoking through postman.

```
@GET
@Path("/customMap")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public JaxrsMapWrapper<String,BookBo> getWarpperMapMsgWithCustomObject()
{
System.out.println("Returning the MapMessage as String and Custom Message ");
Map<String,BookBo> originalMap=new  HashMap<>();
originalMap.put("a",new BookBo(1,"Jinesh"));
JaxrsMapWrapper<String,BookBo> jaxRsMapWrapper=new JaxrsMapWrapper();
jaxRsMapWrapper.setMap(originalMap);
return jaxRsMapWrapper;
}
```

Below is the code for the User defined Java Object BookBo.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class BookBo implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public BookBo() {

    }

    public BookBo(Integer id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    //getters and setters of the field
}
```

What am I missing in the above code due to which while writing the Map in response is not working?