# How to set Map<String,Set<String>> in Rest API with jersey jar

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to insert user from API call. There are normal parameters in Bean like first name, last name, etc.

There is one field in Bean like `Map<String, Set<String>> userExtraFieldMap;`

I am calling my API using Postman & all user details are auto set in Bean when get request except userExtraFieldMap.

Code is working properly for `Content-Type: application/json` but not working for `Content-Type: application/xml`

`userExtraFieldMap` parameter is non mandatory.

**UserDetails.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id", "name", "userExtraFieldMap""})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonRootName("user")
@Schema(description="The UserDetails Response Model",name="UserDetailsModel")
public class UserDetails implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @POJOMappingAnnotation (destinationFieldName = "userId")
    private int id;

    @POJOMappingAnnotation (ignoreSetValue = true)
    private UserName name;

    @XmlElement(name="userExtraFields")
    @JsonProperty("userExtraFields")
    private Map<String,Set<String>> userExtraFieldMap;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UserName getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(UserName name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Map<String, Set<String>> getUserExtraFieldMap() {
        return userExtraFieldMap;
    }

    public void setUserExtraFieldMap(Map<String, Set<String>> userExtraFieldMap) {
        this.userExtraFieldMap = userExtraFieldMap;
    }
```

**UserAPI.java**

```
    @POST
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @JacksonFeatures(serializationEnable = SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)    
    public Response createUser(@Parameter(description="Version Of API",example="2") @PathParam("version") String version, UserDetails user) throws Exception {
     ...
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code of `createUser` ?

Comment: API is called using postman & createUser code is already posted in UserAPI.java

Comment: How is Struts related to this endpoint?

Comment: Resolved using 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941479/jaxb-how-to-marshall-map-into-keyvalue-key