# EclipseLink Throwing Exception?

Tags: jersey, eclipselink

i'm working on a project based on jersey implementation of REST,and i i'm using JPA for persistence,spring IoC for DI.Now i have some objects that must be marshalled with JAXB (MOXy).Following step by step [this tuto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941479/jaxb-how-to-marshall-map-into-keyvalue-key) i tried to get things working but unfortunately i haven't succeeded yet.The folling are my classes,if you can help please:

Root classe :

```java
package com.persistent.entity;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement
public class Bar {  
    private Map<String,String> mapbar;

    public Bar() {

    }

    public Bar(Map<String,String> map ){
        this.mapbar = map;
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
    public Map<String, String> getMapbar() {
        return mapbar;
    }

    public void setMapbar(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.mapbar = map;
    }
}
```

MapAdapter class :

```java
package com.persistent.entity;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

//import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedMap, Map<String, String>>  {

    @Override
    public AdaptedMap marshal(Map<String, String> map) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = document.createElement("bar");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);

        for(Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Element mapElement = document.createElement(entry.getKey());
            mapElement.setNodeValue(entry.getValue());
            rootElement.appendChild(mapElement);
        }

        AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
        adaptedMap.setValue(document);
        return adaptedMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(AdaptedMap adaptedMap) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element rootElement = (Element) adaptedMap.getValue();
        NodeList childNodes = rootElement.getChildNodes();
        for(int x=0,size=childNodes.getLength(); x<size; x++) {
            Node childNode = childNodes.item(x);
            if(childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                map.put(childNode.getLocalName(), childNode.getTextContent());
            }
        }
        return map;
    }  
}
```

AdaptedMap class :

```java
package com.persistent.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;

//import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class AdaptedMap {

    private Object value;

    @XmlAnyElement
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }    
}
```

and, finally, the resource class :

```java
package com.persistent.rest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.persistent.entity.Bar;
import com.persistent.entity.BarList;
import com.persistent.entity.Pie;
import com.persistent.entity.Vente;
import com.persistent.entity.VentesList;
import com.persistent.entity.PieList;
import com.persistent.service.VenteService;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONWithPadding;

// The Java class will be hosted at the URI path "/myresource"
@Path("/myresource")
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class MyResource {

    @Autowired
    VenteService venteService;


    @GET
    @Produces("application/x-javascript")

    public JSONWithPadding getBarService(@QueryParam("callback")  String callback){
        int i;

        VentesList ventes =  venteService.getAll();
        Map<String,String> hmBar = new HashMap<String,String>();

  for (i=0;i<ventes.getsimpleVentes().size();i++){
hmBar.put(ventes.getsimpleVentes().get(i).getProjet(),String.valueOf(
    ventes.getsimpleVentes().get(i).getNbrRsrv()));

}   

  Bar ba = new Bar(hmBar);
    return  new JSONWithPadding(ba,callback);
    } 
}
```

After running this on Tomcat i get this Exception :

```
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet Jersey Spring Web Application a généré une exception
java.io.IOException: Error marshalling JAXB object of type "class com.persistent.entity.Bar".
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:145)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:254)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:578)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:502)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:493)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:308)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:314)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred marshalling the object
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-3001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [{Dyar Al Baydae=6, TEST=8, test=5, Dyar Al Bahja=20, Dyar Al Mansour=87}], of class [class java.util.HashMap], could not be converted to [class com.persistent.entity.AdaptedMap].]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:326)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:167)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:143)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0):

i found an other solution to my problem based on the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820092/jaxb-hashmap-unmappable/8770027#8770027)...It's worked for me and i think is the best solution to the mapping of object of type HashMap.