# How do i map xml attribute values to keys in properties file?

Tags: java, xml, properties-file

### This my test.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Class name="AirwayBill">
    <Attribute name="billNo" primary="true" />
    <Attribute name="date" primary="true" />
    <Attribute name="person" class_name="Person" />
</Class>
<Class name="Person">
    <Attribute name="perId" primary="true" />
    <Attribute name="fname" primary="false" />
    <Attribute name="lname" primary="false" />
```

There is also a `.properties` file containing key value pairs like `billNO=12345`, 
`date=16/07/2014`.
I want to map attributes between each corresponding key from properties and xml files.
How do i do that?
I am able to read both, attribute values and keys, and I am storing each one in a List.

Comment: I am confuse, would you mind rewording the question? do you want to convert data in properties file into XML ? or XML into properties file? I saw an example XML in your question but what does it have to do with your question? The word 'map' is too vague.

Comment: List is not a very useful collection in this case. If you load the properties into a (Hash)Map you'll have a far easier time fetching the correct information.

Comment: billNo = 1234
date = 25/07/2014
perid=12
fname = avc
lname = gfrefe 
billNo = 1235
date = 28/07/2014
perid=13
fname = wss
lname = gfds
 this is my .properties file. i want to map as in i mean to say i want to tag the keys in properties file to xml attributes. for that i need to store keys only not their values right? thats y m using Set to read only Keys(not the values) from properties file. and also m storing the xml attrbutes names in List. now my question is how do i relate these attributes stored in list to keys stored in set

Answer (score 1):

if you want something like this:

```
<someBean>
    <properties>
        <myProperty1>My Value 1</myProperty1>
        <myProperty2>My Value 1</myProperty2>
    </properties>
</someBean>
```

for a map:

```
My Property 1    My Value 1 
My Property 2    My Value 2
```

code:

```
@XmlAnyElement
public List<JAXBElement<String>> getXmlProperties() {
    List<JAXBElement<String>> elements = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<String>>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> property: properties.entrySet()) {
        elements.add(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(property.getKey()), 
            String.class, property.getValue()));
    }

    return elements;
}
```

This is the link which might be useful for you: [Use JAXB XMLAnyElement type of style to return dynamic element names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21407907/7020538)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @GhostCat Oh Sorry... i am new to posting answers in stackoverflow that's why. I ll definitely consider this from now onwards. :)