# JAXB using the value of variable as XML tag

Tags: java, jaxb

y question is simple but I didn´t find anyone else with the same problem.
I am trying to use JAXB to create a XML,so
I have the class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Container{
private String name;
private String value;

public Container(String name, String value){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Using the marshal :

public class Demo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Container.class);

    Container container = new Container("potatoes","5");


    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(container, System.out);
  }
 }
```

The output that I receive is:

```
<Container>
<name>potatoes</name>
<value>5</value>
 </Container>
```

is there any way of the output be like:

```
<Container>
<potatoes>5</potatoes>
</Container>
```

Using the JAXB?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293493/dynamic-tag-names-with-jaxb

Comment: the output you want...potatoes = 5 and value = 5. (5 is being repeated). It does not make much sense. a tag would normally have some information within it.... may be you need to reconsider your need/design OR may be you gave a wrong example.

Comment: This is an example. Of course I want to do something a little more meaningful. Nevertheless I adjusted the example :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use an @XmlAnyElement-annotated property and return element as JAXBElement:

```
@XmlAnyElement
public JAXBElement<String> getThing() {
    return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(this.name), String.class, this.value);
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that reverse (xml -> object) will not be possible