# @XmlElement - Get String value from object that is not mapped with @xml-anotation

Tags: java, xml, xml-binding

I have 2 entities:

```
   @Entity
   @XmlRootElement
   public class test {
       @Getter
       @Setter
       @XmlElement(HERE I WANT THE NAME OF THE COUNTRY)
       private Country country
   }

   @Entity
   public class Country {
      @Getter
      @Setter
      private String name;

      @Getter
      @Setter
      private String capital;  
   }
```

Is there some magic I can use to get the name of the country for the @XmlElement as a simple String without wrap the country entity with @Xml-annotations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293493/dynamic-tag-names-with-jaxb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` for your `Country` type:

```
public static class CountryXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Country> {

    @Override
    public Country unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        Country c =  new Country();
        c.setName(v);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Country v) throws Exception {
        return v != null ? v.getName() : null;
    }
}
```

Then you simply annotate your country field like that:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class test {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlElement(name = "country")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CountryXmlAdapter.class)
    private Country country
}
```

Or, if you care about one-way marshalling only, try creating a method `getCountryName()` in your `test` class and annotate *it* with `@XmlElement`.