# Convert List<String> into below xml format in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have list of String in Java and I wanted to convert it into xml using JaxB or any other tool. It should produce output like following.
Consider EmployeeData is class already defined there with @XmlRootElement(name = "EmployeeData") and in that class I have

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "EmployeeData")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class EmployeeData {
   List<String> employee = new ArrayList<>();

   @XmlElement(name = "employee")
   public List<String> getEmployee() {
     return employee;
   }
}
```

Example:

```
employee.add("A");
employee.add("B");
employee.add("C");
```

And I wanted to convert above employee list into following XML format.

```
<EmployeeData>
    <employee1>A</employee1>
    <employee2>B</employee2>
    <employee3>C</employee3>
<EmployeeData>
```

And What I'm getting is right now

```
<EmployeeData>
    <employee>A</employee>
    <employee>B</employee>
    <employee>C</employee>
<EmployeeData>
```

Can someone provide me solution on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic tag names with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293493/dynamic-tag-names-with-jaxb)